# LinkButton C# OnClick event not firing within Formview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, webforms, code-behind, asplinkbutton

I am having an issue with my "save" linkbutton firing and am at a loss.  I have included the code for the form and code-behind.  I have added some testing to see if the event is firing and it doesn't appear to be so.  Any help is appreciated.  I am a novice coder so excuse me if there are obvious issues or a better way to proceed.  Ultimate goal is to update the entry in the database for the given screen info and then redisplay to updated info.

Again thank you in advance.

```
UPDATE: I have included the FULL-ish CODE: (removed the sensitive info)
```

CODEBEHIND:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class matter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...        
    }

    protected void fvdoc_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            throw new Exception("Clicked");
        }
        throw new Exception("i've been Clicked");
    }
}
```

PAGE:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="matter.aspx.cs" Inherits="matter" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <title>Wasatch Client Matter Index</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' type='text/css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/Site.css" />
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center " style="align-content:center;">Matter Index </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
                <asp:FormView ID="fvdoc" runat="server" DataSourceID="gvdb" OnItemCommand="fvdoc_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h2 class="col-md-12"><asp:Label ID="tbname" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("docid") %> /> - <asp:Label ID="lbID" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("sName") %> /></h2>

                                <div class="left col-md-10"> 
                                    <legend>Matter Info:</legend>
                                       <div class="form-group"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Matter" AssociatedControlID="dcname"/>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="dcname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sDocname") %> Enabled="true"/></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-10">
                                    <hr />
                                        <div class="form-group"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Notes/Comments" AssociatedControlID="dcnotes" />
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="dcnotes" runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine" Text=<%# Bind("sdocdesc") %> Enabled="true"/></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 txsmall"> 
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Filed: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblfiledate" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtFiledate") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true" />
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Modified: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblmodify" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtLastModified") + " - " + Bind("susermodified") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true"/>

                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="txsmall" id="lbltest"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear-fix col-md-12">
                                   <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Move" ID="MoveButton" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="False" href="m.aspx" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Home" ID="HomeButton" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="False" href="default.aspx"/>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:FormView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" />

    </form>

    </div>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are saying that "it doesn't appear to be so". What kind of testing have you tried? Have you tried to add a break-point on it?

Comment: Yes.  I have used breakpoints, raiseerror, etc.

Comment: Can you do `protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  throw new Exception("I've been click");
}` and see what you get? Sorry because I look so suspicious, but your code seems pretty valid.

Comment: I agree that is why I am confused.  I ran with the throw and no change.

Comment: Do you have the OnClick button code on the same page as the asp.net aspx code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link button is present inside a formview item template as can be seen below and thus you will not get the individual control event (`onclick` event of linkbutton). Rather you need to handle the [`FormView.ItemCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and do your processing like

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvdoc" runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="gvdb" onitemcommand="itemCommandClick">

<ItemTemplate>

.......
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" .........
```

In code behind handle this like

```
void itemCommandClick(Object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        LinkButton button = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
        //Do rest of the processing 
    }
}
```

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="matter.aspx.cs" Inherits="matter" %>

Comment: @MikeC, my bad didn't seen your post properly. See edited answer if that helps.

Comment: Added that. ` <asp:FormView ID="fvdoc" runat="server" DataSourceID="gvdb" OnItemCommand="fvdoc_ItemCommand">`  BUTTON: `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />`  CODEBEHIND: `protected void fvdoc_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            throw new Exception("Clicked");
        }
        throw new Exception("i've been Clicked");
    }`  still not firing

Comment: I added the two throws so I could see which one fired. Neither fire.

Comment: The link address is : `javascript:__doPostBack('fvdoc$SaveButton','')`  which looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FormView` is missing the `EditItemTemplate`, like so:

```
            <asp:FormView ID="fvdoc" runat="server" DataSourceID="gvdb" OnItemCommand="fvdoc_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <!--... Use readonly controls like Label etc...-->
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="EditButton" CommandName="Edit" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <!--... Use editable controls like TextBox etc...-->
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
```

For the click on the Edit Button, change to Edit mode, then Handle the Save button to save the new values.

See the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.edititemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.